# ART dump JAVA Stack when DumpForSigQuit

Tags: java, android, stack, runtime, abort

this crash only happened on android 9.x. when art DumpForSigQuit, it meet recursively abort. Does anyone else meet this abort? It can be successful some time when android anr happened. but sometimes, it can meet this abort when dump trace for android anr, ant it always abort at dump java stack. 
Will be really appreciate your answers!!

```
   >>> backtrace <<<
    #00 pc 0001ccb6  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+57)
    #01 pc 0034e683  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+910)
    #02 pc 000071b3  /system/lib/libbase.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD2Ev+494)
    #03 pc 003a0495  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20GetMethodIdxOfInvokeEPKNS_11InstructionE+204)
    #04 pc 0039f105  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20VerifyInvocationArgsEPKNS_11InstructionENS0_10MethodTypeEb+28)
    #05 pc 003982b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier25CodeFlowVerifyInstructionEPj+5524)
    #06 pc 00396a93  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20CodeFlowVerifyMethodEv+214)
    #07 pc 003954ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier14VerifyCodeFlowEv+576)
    #08 pc 003938ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier6VerifyEv+5762)
    #09 pc 00394c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier16FindLocksAtDexPcEv+88)
    #10 pc 00394bcb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier16FindLocksAtDexPcEPNS_9ArtMethodEjPNSt3__16vectorINS1_11DexLockInfoENS4_9allocatorIS6_EEEEj+406)
    #11 pc 002d854f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor10VisitLocksEPNS_12StackVisitorEPFvPNS_6mirror6ObjectEPvES6_b+470)
    #12 pc 0037bd43  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art26MonitorObjectsStackVisitor10VisitFrameEv+94)
    #13 pc 00361aef  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12StackVisitor9WalkStackILNS0_16CountTransitionsE0EEEvb+518)
    #14 pc 003729d7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DumpJavaStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbb+206)
    #15 pc 0036f4ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+278)
    #16 pc 0036bc73  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+34)
    #17 pc 00384bb5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+744)
    #18 pc 0037f13b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureES2_+1162)
    #19 pc 0037e2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+404)
    #20 pc 0034e42f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+314)
    #21 pc 000071b3  /system/lib/libbase.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD2Ev+494)
    #22 pc 003a0495  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20GetMethodIdxOfInvokeEPKNS_11InstructionE+204)
    #23 pc 0039f105  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20VerifyInvocationArgsEPKNS_11InstructionENS0_10MethodTypeEb+28)
    #24 pc 003982b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier25CodeFlowVerifyInstructionEPj+5524)
    #25 pc 00396a93  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20CodeFlowVerifyMethodEv+214)
    #26 pc 003954ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier14VerifyCodeFlowEv+576)
    #27 pc 003938ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier6VerifyEv+5762)
    #28 pc 00394c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier16FindLocksAtDexPcEv+88)
    #29 pc 00394bcb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier16FindLocksAtDexPcEPNS_9ArtMethodEjPNSt3__16vectorINS1_11DexLockInfoENS4_9allocatorIS6_EEEEj+406)
    #30 pc 002d854f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor10VisitLocksEPNS_12StackVisitorEPFvPNS_6mirror6ObjectEPvES6_b+470)
    #31 pc 0037bd43  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art26MonitorObjectsStackVisitor10VisitFrameEv+94)
    #32 pc 00361aef  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12StackVisitor9WalkStackILNS0_16CountTransitionsE0EEEvb+518)
    #33 pc 003729d7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DumpJavaStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbb+206)
    #34 pc 0036f4ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+278)
    #35 pc 0036bc73  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+34)
    #36 pc 00384bb5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+744)
    #37 pc 0037f13b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureES2_+1162)
    #38 pc 0037e469  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+784)
    #39 pc 0037e087  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+614)
    #40 pc 00358209  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+120)
```